# using Blue-Orange Diverging color in a ggplot map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use Blue-Orange Diverging color gradient with my ggplot map. I have found that it is available in ggthemes as document [here](https://jrnold.github.io/ggthemes/reference/tableau_gradient_pal.html) but how can I include it in my code?

Reproducible Example

```
library(ggplot2)
statesMap = map_data("state")
statesMap$num = rnorm(nrow(statesMap))

 ggplot(statesMap, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = num)) + 
 geom_polygon(color = "black") + scale_fill_gradient(name = "num",low = 
 "#B8E6E6", high = "darkblue", guide = "colorbar",na.value="white")
```

The code above gives the map below but I want to create similar to the Tableau map at the bottom.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scale_fill_gradient2_tableau`](https://jrnold.github.io/ggthemes/reference/scale_colour_gradient2_tableau.html) and choose the desired palette

```
Tableau diverging colour scales (continuous)

    scale_colour_gradient2_tableau(palette = "Orange-Blue Diverging", ...,
      na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar")

    scale_fill_gradient2_tableau(palette = "Orange-Blue Diverging", ...,
      na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar")

    scale_color_gradient2_tableau(palette = "Orange-Blue Diverging", ...,
      na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar")

Arguments

Palette name.

    "ordered-sequential""Blue-Green Sequential", "Blue Light", "Orange Light", "Blue", "Orange", "Green", "Red", "Purple", "Brown", "Gray", "Gray Warm", "Blue-Teal", "Orange-Gold", "Green-Gold", "Red-Gold", "Classic Green", "Classic Gray", "Classic Blue", "Classic Red", "Classic Orange", "Classic Area Red", "Classic Area Green", "Classic Area-Brown"

    "ordered-diverging""Orange-Blue Diverging", "Red-Green Diverging", "Green-Blue Diverging", "Red-Blue Diverging", "Red-Black Diverging", "Gold-Purple Diverging", "Red-Green-Gold Diverging", "Sunset-Sunrise Diverging", "Orange-Blue-White Diverging", "Red-Green-White Diverging", "Green-Blue-White Diverging", "Red-Blue-White Diverging", "Red-Black-White Diverging", "Orange-Blue Light Diverging", "Temperature Diverging", "Classic Red-Green", "Classic Red-Blue", "Classic Red-Black", "Classic Area Red-Green", "Classic Orange-Blue", "Classic Green-Blue", "Classic Red-White-Green", "Classic Red-White-Black", "Classic Orange-White-Blue", "Classic Red-White-Black Light", "Classic Orange-White-Blue Light", "Classic Red-White-Green Light", "Classic Red-Green Light"

... Arguments passed to tableau_gradient_pal.
na.value: Colour to use for missing values
guide: Type of legend. Use 'colourbar' for continuous colour bar, or 'legend' for discrete colour legend.
```

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

statesMap <- map_data("state")
statesMap$num <- rnorm(nrow(statesMap))

ggplot(statesMap, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = num)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2_tableau(palette = "Orange-Blue Diverging")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(statesMap, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = num)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2_tableau(palette = "Orange-Blue-White Diverging")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to reverse it? use Blue-Orange-White Diverging?

Comment: I don't think it's possible because I don't see any `direction = -1` option inside that function